# How do I find out what political party a state Supreme Court justice is affiliated with when it's hidden from public

Tags: united-states, election

Judges hide their political party affiliations from voters when running for election in WA State Supreme Court Justice positions. I know they're not supposed to be partisan, but much of their work is done from their beliefs.  Is there any way the voters can find out their hidden party affiliations?

Comment: The underlying assumption here seems to be that each justice actually _has_ a political party affiliation.

Comment: I would say that this is a poor way to judge their beliefs as there is a wide gap of what is a tenant of the party held by a member of the Party in the US.  Not all Democrats believe all the Democratic positions and vice versa for Republicans.  Though the best general method would probably be look at who appointed the Judge.

Answer (score 1):

[According to ballotpedia.org](https://ballotpedia.org/Washington_Supreme_Court_elections,_2018) only Supreme Court Position 8 is contested in 2108 WA, the choices being either:

- [**Steven Gonzalez**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Gonzalez) (Incumbent)

  > Gonzalez was appointed by Democratic Governor Chris Gregoire in November 2011 to a term that commenced in 2012. He was elected to
  >   the court in 2012 for a term that began in January 2013 and expires
  >   on January 13, 2019.   **-- [BP](https://ballotpedia.org/Steven_Gonzalez)**

  Gonzalez was appointed by a Democrat, and is endorsed by the major
  papers as well as [liberal papers and WA's Democrats](https://justicegonzalez.com/endorsements/).  Presumably
  he'd have to be a liberal.
- [**Nathan Choi**](https://www.nathanchoiforjudge.org/)

  Choi seems to be an eccentric and outspoken conspiracy theorist who
  [champions the appointment of Justice Brett Kavanaugh](https://www.nathanchoiforjudge.org/), (but his favorite Justice is Clarence Thomas), appears to
  be a [9-11 "Truther"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9/11_Truth_movement), and sometimes misses a few typos (*i.e.* "never not"):

  > Nathan Choi will be a Rule of Law Judge and never not take a quarter of a Millon Dollars from individuals or entities with Elite
  >   Globalist ties.

Comment: Do you have a source for the libertarian label? Did he call so himself? If the website you linked to is his, then the rants against "Illegals" and "Elite Globalist / New World Order / Rothschild" (all code for Jews) would suggest that he is at least not an average libertarian, but on the far right.

Comment: @tim, The "source" is only my own fuzzy estimate, but includes the qualifiers *"eccentric and outspoken"*.  It's unclear that *"the far right"* would be more accurate due to [Choi's alleged *pro bono* work as an immigration lawyer](https://www.nathanchoiforjudge.org/union-members-immigration/).   *"Mostly far right"* maybe?  (Feel free to modify the label to whatever seems most accurate.)

Comment: Or maybe Choi is a refreshingly honest man? ;)

Comment: @Orangesandlemons, *"“Readin' don't never not done nothing for not nonebody. Never not no one, didn't about no reason not never. And by God they never not ain't gonna will!”*

― [Early Cuyler](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/753086-readin-don-t-never-not-done-nothing-for-not-nonebody-never)

Comment: @agc I edited it to the more general "conspiracy theorist". He might be Libertarian - and if so, probably some far-right variant -, but I don't think we have enough to go on to specifically label him as such. But going by his website, it shouldn't be in question that he is a conspiracy theorist (that's the primary content on his website).

Comment: @tim, OK, but: political crimes and conspiracies certainly exist, (*e.g.* Watergate, Jim Crow, *etc*), so we shouldn't deprecate such theory in general, but rather just the sort of sensational but weak or shaky theories that Choi favors in particular.